# testing google sheet editor addon fails with error 403

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization, add-on

I have a Sheets editor addon. it is a stand alone project connected to a standard google cloud project (as opposed to the default project).

I want to "Publish -> Test as add-on..." from the legacy editor menu.

1. I choose one document owned by same account
2. Set "installed and enabled" on the bottom of the same screen
3. addon is now added to the document Addon menu
4. When launching the addon, there's a prompt for Authorization approval.
5. but at the end I get an Authorization error 403.
   see attached screen shoot.

[This youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_NPvk0pk8g) video suggest to add a user in the OAuth consent screen. so I did, but it didn't help.

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Did you add the email address of the user who is executing the add-on for testing?

Comment: @ale13 At least, I think I did it. I'm new to all this, so maybe I am missing something. However, I say again, all (GCP, app script , tested spreadsheet, owner of all as well as the tested user) are the same single user

Comment: Would you mind double checking? Even though you are the owner, you should still add your address to the "Test users" section.

Comment: @ale13 you were actually right. I was sure I did it but I've double checked, and somehow it wasn't configured. Don't understand. Maybe I did it in another place, I am still kind of lost in all the GPC dashboard screens. Anyway, I added the mail, and now it is looks OK for now. If you will write an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Creating the OAuth screen is not enough for this - you should also add some *Test users* for this.

Even though you are the owner of the project, you should still add your address to the "Test users" section if you are the one who is testing the add-on.